# Cannot run same python file in PyCharm and in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a script that runs and complete itself on visual Studio 2017.

The same file and with the same packages installed in pyCharm Community 2018.3.5 starts and it stops at the following line with no obvious error indication

```
records = p.map(parse, web_links)
        print('Records Parsed')
        if len(records) > 0:
            for record in records:
                with open('output.csv', 'a') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
                    writer.writerow(record)
            print('Records Output Success')
```

What do I miss here? what else should I check apart the same packages installed?
I am running them on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Do you have the same packages installed with the same version each?

Comment: Yes double checked

Comment: Does the indentation you're showing us here match what's in your file? There's no reason do indent at the first `print()`; this would cause an `IndentationError`. Please make sure the code you share with us is accurate; we can't be expected to guess which errors are releavant.

Comment: Shouldnt be an notification error your indentation is wrong?

Comment: If there's an indentation error, yes. That's why I'm asking for clarification. Again, we shouldn't have to guess what's relevant and what isn't.

Comment: "with no obvious error indication"—is there a breakpoint set in PyCharm?

Comment: This is a side issue, but why are you opening and closing the csv file for each record?

Comment: @chris No breakpoint at that line I put now a breakpoint there but it seems normal..

Comment: @John you mean it should be opposite with open..for record in records ?

Comment: You still haven't fixed your indentation. **Again**, is your code actually indented this way? Please fix it.